# document.referrer not defined for internal links

Tags: javascript

I'm currently building a websites and host it (with https activated) and it seems that I have access to the `document.referrer` (which is filled) when accessing from google for instance.

However, when I'm clicking a link inside my website, the `document.referrer` becomes empty and I can't use it.

Is it something "normal"? How can I access `document.referrer` from inside my website (using internal links, no subdomains implied)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

I m using a framework that relies on client-side navigation and that doesn't set the referrer under the hood.

As a workaround, when JS is activated, I m watching route transitions and attache the previous route to the location state so that I know where I am in the navigation tree.